# Unable to set a default language in OpenOffice.org programs

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I'm having lots of problems with the default language in OpenOffice.org applications.

I've set the language in **Tools > Options > Language Settings** but whenever I open the app it has no language set and therefore no spell checking.

I've then set it by clicking on one of the boxes at the bottom of the screen of an open document. It flips language sporadically or so it seems.

Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Comment: What OS are you on? What is your default OS system language?